# DataStore AndroidStudio

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, coroutine

I'm looking to store some data with android and I try to use datastore ( jetpack android).

I got actualy :

```
class StoreToken(context:Context){
    private val dataStore = context.createDataStore(name = "token")
    companion object{
        val TOKEN_ACCESS_CIPHER_KEY = preferencesKey<String>("TOKEN_ACCESS_CIPHER")
    }

    suspend fun storeToken(accessCipher: String){
        dataStore.edit {
            it[TOKEN_ACCESS_CIPHER_KEY] = accessCipher
        }
    }

    val accessCipher = dataStore.data.map{ it[TOKEN_ACCESS_CIPHER_KEY] ?: "none" }

}
```

I store my access_cipher_key right there :
In an kotlin class who make an api call with OkHttp

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    StoreToken(context).storeToken("key")
}
```

So now when I try to read it, I do that : ( I dot it probably wrong ):

```
class HomeLoggedActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var storeToken: StoreToken

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_logged)

        storeToken = StoreToken(this)
        storeToken.accessCipher


    }
}
```

I have try lot of things to read it ( iterate, to string, ... )
I think it's probably an async bug or my thinking process is bad with async

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution ::

```
GlobalScope.launch {
        storeToken.accessCipher.collect {
            println(it)
}
```

Just use .collect ! ( You need te be in an coroutine, this why I use globalScope right there )